# Is it possible to read cpp file like a txt file?

Tags: javascript, c++

Im working on a web-based C++ IDE-like project. I wanted to add an open button in which the user can open not just a text file (done with that) but a .cpp file too. Will that be possible?

Here is the code which opens .txt files and append to my contenteditable div.

```
function readSingleFile(evt) {

      var f = evt.target.files[0];
      //console.log(f);
      if (!f) {
          alert("Failed to load file");
          return;
      }
      if (f.name.indexOf('.txt') == -1) {
          alert(f.name + " is not a valid text file.");
          return;
      }

      var r = new FileReader();
      r.onload = function (e) {
          var contents = e.target.result; //.replace("\r\n","<br/>");
          contents = contents.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
          alert("Got the file.n" + "name: " + f.name + "n" + "type: " + f.type + "n" + "size: " + f.size + " bytesn" + "contents: " + contents);


          var tmpSent = "";
          var newContents = "";
          for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
              if(contents.charAt(i) == '\n') {
                  newContents += "<div>"+tmpSent+"</div>";
                  tmpSent = "";
              }
              else
                  tmpSent += contents.charAt(i);
          };
          if(tmpSent.length>0)
                  newContents += "<div>"+tmpSent+"</div>";

          console.log(newContents);
          document.getElementById('board').innerHTML = newContents;
      }
      r.readAsText(f);

  }

  document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/88vtR/33/

Comment: A `.cpp` file is usually a text file.

Comment: Why would it be any different?

Comment: cpp is a text file that contains more than a text, is that it?

Comment: On windows file extensions are for the sole purpose of associating particular file with a program that can handle it. So as others are suggesting - regular text file is not different than a c/c++ source file (from your point of view). Formatting c/c++ file is a different story ..

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the presented code i see it forces only opening .txt files

```
  if (f.name.indexOf('.txt') == -1) {
      alert(f.name + " is not a valid text file.");
      return;
  }
```

I would add a check for a .cpp as well in it if you want to keep the same approach.

Not sure of the other code involved but i would use a open file dialog that only allows the file extensions you want and that would make the mentioned check redundant.

Comment: i don't see any need for an extension check. what if they wanted to edit an ini file or a make file? why make an editor for just one kind of file unless it parses that format?